# Java Regexp capturing group includes space, why?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse this string,

```
"斬釘截鐵 斩钉截铁 [zhan3 ding1 jie2 tie3] /to chop the nail and slice the iron (idiom)/resolute and decisive/unhesitating/definitely/without any doubt/";
```

With this code

```
private static final Pattern TRADITIONAL = Pattern.compile("(.*?) ");

    private String extractSinglePattern(String row, Pattern pattern) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(row);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However, for some reason the string returned contains a space at the end

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<斬釘截鐵[]> but was:<斬釘截鐵[ ]>
```

Is there something wrong with my pattern?
I have also tried

```
private static final Pattern TRADITIONAL = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s");
```

but to no avail

I have also tried matching with two spaces at the end of the pattern, but it doesn't match (there is only one space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [`Matcher.group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) which is documented as:

> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

The *match* includes the space. The *capturing group* within the match doesn't, but you haven't asked for that.

If you change your return statement to:

```
return matcher.group(1);
```

then I believe it'll do what you want.

Comment: Just a suggestion: why not use `(.*?) +` to be covered for multiple spaces?

Comment: Marko, I believe the format is fixed at one space.. so I'd rather keep it like that unless I find out otherwise

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression `(.+?)(?=\s+)`

Comment: The non-capturing group is redundant here. It has only one member.